# android sockets with a connect screen, that opens a new screen if a successful connection occurs

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I need to design an application that opens to a screen with a button that says connect, and when the connect button is hit, it initiates a socket connection, and if the connection is successful it launches a new screen, but once the connection is faulted I need it to return to the connection screen. I know I need to run the networking actions in a async task thread, I am just not sure about what kind of logic to use to initiate the task, and have the async task network thread return a true value if th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask has onPostExecute method which runs on the UI thread. There you can check whether the socket connection is a success or not, and start an activity using StartActivity.

You can pass the URL to the class constructor that extends asynctask and using this url, you could start the socket connection.

hope that helps.

Comment: Ok I have another question for you, what would be the best course of action for sending a message over the connection, and receiving a response every few seconds? Would it be best to use a thread, async task, or a service? If I am correct ASYNC tasks only run once, until re run.

Comment: thats right, AsyncTask runs only once. You can do the entire operation in a thread or in a service. Service might be a costly when compared to threads. You could go with threads and use a handler to communicate with the main thread if you need to update the UI.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I ended up using a main thread with a loop that creates a socket if a connection is not made, and when the socket is connected another loop is initiated that creates a data input and output buffer, and runs a "run on UI" thread to update variables, and this process repeats until the connection is terminated.